# Difference in remote branches in git

Tags: git, remote-branch

When I clone our repository from the server fresh, I see much less remote branches than on the clone that existed for a while now:

```
$ git branch -r | wc -l
      90

$ git branch -r | wc -l
     376
```

At times we 'clean' old branches by tagging and deleting them. It seems that the 'old' repository clone does not pick up these changes. Or is there an other explanation for the difference?

Is there a way to force the old repository to only see the remote branches as with the fresh clone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a

```
git fetch --prune
```

to remove obsolete references